# Python if output of a function

Tags: regex, python-3.x, if-statement

I am using the following code to find repeated characters in a string

```
import re
S=input()

m = re.search(r'([A-Za-z0-9])\1+',S.strip())

if m:
    print(m.group(1))
else:
    print(-1)
```

I am not sure why "if m:" works for me and what does it do? Does it check if m exists? (which I believe it should exist anyway), does it check if the value of m is bigger than zero?

P.S: If my input string (S) has no repeated value, then print(m) gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if m:` evaluates the expression `m` and checks if its value is "truthy", that is, if `bool(m)` is `True`. If it is, the body of the `if` block is executed.

If the name `m` doesn't exist, a `NameError` will be produced *while evaluating* the expression `m`.

Also, if `S` doesn't have a repeated value (for example, it's empty), `print(m)` *will not* give you an error:

```
>>> S = ''  # empty
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'([A-Za-z0-9])\1+',S.strip())
>>> print(m)
None  # not an error: this just indicates that the regex didn't find anything
```

Note that `bool(None) == False`.